# How to provide AOSP screen size information?

Tags: android, android-firmware

Recently I bought Xiaomi MI Pad 4 with custom multilanguage MIUI and decided to install pure Android on to the device.

I found an [article](https://www.getdroidtips.com/mi-pad-4-android-9-0-pie/#Guide_to_Install_AOSP_Android_90_Pie_on_Mi_Pad_4) and installed [phhusson GSI](https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations/releases)
All works fine but it seems Android doesn't know anything abount the Tablet phisical screen size. I see very big fonts and pictures like if usual phone was inlarged.

And my question is how to make the tablet work as a tablet, not as a big phone?

Answer (score 0):

Author of GSI [anwered](https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations/issues/383). 
There is cool command

> adb shell wm density 240

and phone screen density changes to 240!